# Combine 2 tables in mysql with different column names in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I want to combine two tables in one query and don't know how to do it, for example:

**Table 1**

| id | description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | description_1 |
| 2 | description_2 |
| 3 | description_3 |
| 4 | description_4 |

**Table 2**

| id | material_name |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | material_name_1 |
| 6 | material_name_2 |
| 7 | material_name_3 |
| 8 | material_name_4 |

ultimately the result of my query should look like this:

| id | description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | description_1 |
| 2 | description_2 |
| 3 | description_3 |
| 4 | description_4 |
| 5 | material_name_1 |
| 6 | material_name_2 |
| 7 | material_name_3 |
| 8 | material_name_4 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `union all` operator:

```sql
SELECT id, description
FROM   table1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, material_name
FROM   table2
```

Comment: Tnx, it helped a lot